# Specialized Roubaix Seat Post Rubber Seal Loose

Tags: seatpost

On my Specialized Roubaix Comp, the rubber seal where the seat post enters the frame works loose and slides up the seat post a little. The seat post itself is not loose and stays put, the issue is just with the seal.  I not sure if the seal serves a functional purpose (i.e. to prevent water ingress) or if it is just for aerodynamics and appearance. However, it bothers me that will not stay put. How do I get it to stay put?

Comment: If it was me, I'd be a little more concerned that it is working loose.  Perhaps that's a symptom of some other issue, maybe unexpected defect or flex in the frame/seatpost

Comment: Is the rubber glazed and smooth?  New rubber tends to be matt and grippy. You might just need a new one; it could be a wear item like brake pads.

Comment: It’s just there for waterproofing and looks. I’d begin by adding a wrap of electrical tape to the seatpost to have a more friction-y surface. If that fails, a little bit of hot glue or something wouldn’t hurt.

Comment: Give it a thin coat of carbon mounting paste to make it 'stickier' and stay in place..